# Selecting and compare one value with values in 2 columns of the DB

Tags: mysql

I have one value, that represents a zip code.

I need to see which city belongs to this zip code by comparing the given value with the values in two columns of the DB.

This is my _cities table:

```
city (name of the city, VARCHAR)
zipcode_start (the first zip code available, VARCHAR )
zipcode_end ( the last zip code available, VARCHAR ).
```

Where I leave zipcodes are numbered in sequence.

So if I have for example: `city = Rome, zipcode_start = 00118 and zipcode_end = 00199` and the given zipcode is `00119`, how do I get the city Rome from the DB?

`00119` in this case is included in the sequence `00118` - `00199`, so the DB should return Rome.

I can do this in many ways with PHP, but I am looking for an elegant way to do it directly with a SQL statement.

Is this possible?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use BETWEEN, or if you don't like that, you can use >= and <=. And if you prefer joins over where clauses, you can even join on an inequality sometimes.

For example,

```
select city
from my_cities
where zipcode between zipcode_start and zipcode_end
```

You have to deal with getting the variable into that statement, but I get the impression that you can handle that part already. Is this what you are trying to do? I sort of doubt it, but that's all I get out of your question.

Comment: This solution will imply knowing what zipcode_start and zipcode_end are. How can I know that if I have to do the select yet?

Comment: @Diego -- glad to hear it. I didn't write the whole syntax because I was not certain which PHP libs you were using. But I'm glad you figured it out.